# Not able to call a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am calling the function `createOne` inside `createProfile` and `createOne` does not appear to be executed. I am trying to create a user in database. The route is working as expected its just i am not able to call function within a function.

Please help!

```
exports.createOne = Model =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("I am in createone")

    const doc = await Model.create(req.body);


    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  });
```

```
exports.createProfile = (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.query.segment);
    if(req.query.segment == "Tour"){
        let Segment = Tour;
        console.log(factory);
        factory.createOne(Tour);
    }

}
```

Kindly find below results of console log the function doesn't fire off at all.

```
Tour
{ getOne: [Function], createOne: [Function] }
POST /api/v1/midasCommon/?segment=Tour - - ms - -
```

Comment: _"i am not able to call function within a function."_ Which function is not getting called?

Comment: Are you able to log something before `catchAsync` in `exports.createOne`?

Comment: @AlexWayne User is trying ti call `createOne` in `createProfile`

Comment: But you say it's logging `POST /api/v1/midasCommon/?segment=Tour - - ms - -` which should mean that `Model.create()` is being called just fine.

Comment: Hi Matt..factory.CreateOne doesn't work rest working properly.

Comment: This is timed log after timout..Expected res.status is 201.

Comment: @Alex: console log at createOne doesn't' fire

Comment: What is that `catchAsync()` function?

Comment: module.exports = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};

Comment: This is a function which caches error in asynchronous function

Comment: All other APis work fine..Only createOne doesn't fire..

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, based on the definition of catchAsync you gave,

```js
const catchAsync = fn => { 
  return (req, res, next) => { 
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

you are returning a function with catchAsync that never gets called. What you do with `factory.createOne(Tour);` is just call catchAsync, but you need one more call.

You can either do `factory.createOne(Tour)();` or change createOne to be:

```js
exports.createOne = Model =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("I am in createone")

    const doc = await Model.create(req.body);


    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  })(); // <-- Notice the call
```

Comment: Hi, That worked but I am not able to access req in createOne function

Comment: Kindly find below the error:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at catchAsync (/home/sagar/NodeProjects/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/controllers/midasHandleFactory.js:26:21)
    at /home/sagar/NodeProjects/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/utils/catchAsync.js:3:7

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28278) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. THis is the error. Please help

Comment: Try to figure out how to pass req and res to the createOne function, given that the first call returns the function returned by catchAsync